# Spring security http basic auth for Rest api with Java config

Tags: spring, api, rest, groovy, basic-authentication

I am trying to secure a CXF based rest API with Spring security. While my configuration technically works, I cannot seem to get the API to respond with JSON rather than an HTML message upon 401. Based on a few other SO posts I put together the following java config, using groovy, for the spring security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Slf4j
class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) {
        http.antMatcher('/api/**')
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers('/api/admin/**').hasRole('ADMIN')
                .antMatchers('/api/**').hasRole('USER')
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(
                    new BasicAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager: authenticationManager(), authenticationEntryPoint: new BasicJsonEntryPoint(realmName: 'Local')),
                    BasicAuthenticationFilter.class
                )
    }

    static class BasicJsonEntryPoint extends BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint {

        @Override
        public void commence(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException e) throws IOException, ServletException {
            log.debug 'Handling response'
            response.addHeader HttpHeaders.WWW_AUTHENTICATE, /Basic realm="${getRealmName()}"/
            response.setStatus HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value()
            response.getWriter().println([status: HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value(), message: e.getMessage()].toJson())
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried numerous variations on this general approach, but no matter what I get HTML back from the API. See the following req/resp:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
        <title>Error 401 Full authentication is required to access this resource</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>HTTP ERROR 401</h2>
        <p>Problem accessing /api/test. Reason:

            <pre>    Full authentication is required to access this resource</pre>
        </p>
        <hr />
        <i>
            <small>Powered by Jetty://</small>
        </i>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just guessing here, but Jetty is a little too helpful sometimes when your application emits http response codes other than 200s.  My recommendation is that you add some  logic to your web.xml to short circuit Jetty's helpfulness.  The full technique that got my application out of a similar issue is documented on:  [How do I suppress Jetty 8's default ErrorHandler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18138595/how-do-i-suppress-jetty-8s-default-errorhandler)

Good luck.

Comment: This does not appear to solve the problem. I tried with Jetty, Tomcat, and Undertow. Same results.